# Intel NUC read only BIOS and the BOOT menu doesn't show up

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, intel-nuc

I have a problem with my Intel NUC DN2820FYK. At the moment there's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed. Now I would like to reinstall it because I've messed it up ab bit too much and would like to start over again. But now I'm facing some very strange problems.

I'm not able to boot from the USB Stick. After the start screen show up with the following information's (not sure with the texts but with the keys^^):

```
> Press F2 for BIOS
> Press F10 for boot menu
```

After I press F10 the password input of the BIOS appears. That's strange because I've never set a password and F10 should throw me into the BOOT menu. After a couple of tries I found out that with leaving the password input field empty I'm able to get into the (UEFI) BIOS menu. So I'm not able to go into the BOOT menu to boot from the USB stick.

After clicking a bit around inside the BIOS menu I've realized that the whole BIOS is in something like `read only` mode (Every option, checkbox and input field is greyed out with no more information's).

What's wrong with my NUC? Are these problems related?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve all my problems after resetting the BIOS password by removing the onboard configuration jumper.